# JSON from JQuery AJAX call bigger than the database itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, database, json

Here's the code:

```
$.ajax({
 url:"http://.....pullEntireDBPopulation.php",
 cache:false,
 datatype:"json",
 success:function(popData){
  alert("Population size: " + popData.length);
  popProducers = new Array();
  for(i=0;i<popData.length;i++){
   popProducers[i] = popData[i].ProducerName;
  }
 });
}
```

I've written the .PHP to pull every piece of data from a database, which I've checked on the browser, so I know it's not that. Still, every time I run the page, it says the array is around 5000 long even though that's larger than the entire database. What's going on???
If it helps, it's also saying that when I write the data into arrays, they are undefined in the array. So there's clearly a problem with the data being read into the page since I know it works on it's own, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: `console.log(popData)` to confirm it is an array or object containing the data you expect it to.

Comment: You might need to re-consider what you're doing with all that data at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. `datatype: "json"` apparently doesn't render the same as `dataType: "json"` I hate when it's stupid things like this! Because it wasn't reading it as a JSON due to my capitalization error, it was just reading in a string rather than an array of objects--> problem.

Answer (score 0):

PopData is Object, not Array. And then `length` can work uncorrectly.
For the same reason you can not apply "`for`".

Try

`popData.size()` or `$(popData).size()`

`popData.each(function(){ popProducers[i] = this.ProducerName; })` (or `$(popData).each`...)

Comment: How do you know `PopData` is an object? A JSON string can represent an array too.

Comment: You're right. But i think he can try to treat it as a variable.
Although it is possible server-side script returns a string instead of json. And so the "length" returns 5000 - the number of characters in the string

Comment: if it wasn't json, jQuery would have fired the fail callback rather than success.

Comment: This is the second ajax call, I've used, and I mimicked it pretty closely just changing the url and removing the data values (as they were not needed). The .php acts just like the first .php, so I'm not sure if that's it, but I'll check it out.